# Struggling with loops and conditions

Tags: .net, powershell, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am querying SQL Server from a PowerShell script and return a value that I store in variable as `$latestVersion`.

I have a folder with 30 files having same static name at the beginning but ends with different day:

```
TEMP.file
TEMP 20181010.file
TEMP 20181011.file
TEMP 20181012.file
...
```

What I am struggling with is the following:

- if `$latestVersion` is only TEMP, I'd like to execute files from 25 to 30 for the purpose I am using an if statement to check
- if `$latestVersion` points to say the 27th file I'd like to execute what's greater than that so -> 28-29-30
- if `$latestVersion` equals the latest file `ECHO I'm ok`

My problem comes from not knowing how to elegantly chuck away `TEMP.file` as in comparisons he is the greater one of them all.

So having a foreach loop

```
function RunFiles([string[]]$released, [string]$latest)
{
    $global:basePoint = "TEMP Hotfix 20181010.file"
    $global:const = "TEMP.file"

    #if only $const is there, run files from $basePoint onwards but exclude $const itself
    if($latest -eq $const)
    {
        foreach($rel in $released)
        {
            if(($rel -lt $latest) -and ($rel -ge $basePoint))
            {
                $install = $rel

                foreach ($i in $install)
                {
                    #run files
                }
            }
        }
    }
    elseif($latest -ne $const)
    {
        foreach($fix in $released)
        {
            if(($fix -ne $const) -and ($fix -gt $latest))
            {
                $upgrade = $fix

                foreach($up in $upgrade)
                {
                    #upgrade with latest
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is `TEMP.file` is always greater and do not know how to work around it

Comment: If you want to execute files (you presume are present) on specific conditions the foreach doesn't make sense. You'll have to parse $latestVersion eventually with a RegEx to get contained year,month and day and do if/elseif/else or a switch. If only TEMP.file you want current year/month ? All these facts are unclear and your question thus too broad.

Comment: TEMP.file is the starting point - if the databases exists that means TEMP.file could be in $latestVersion, the question is he sits with the rest of files in same dir, and when I do the conditions `greater than` some file, TEMP.file is always greater, eventhough I don't want it to be installed, but I am using it as a starting point if he is the actual $latestVersion, then I have to skip 15 files and install the rest till the end. I didn't mention I am sorting the files with the query, therefore no need of getting the year/month etc.?

Comment: Your example states specific dates, if this is a one time job, do it manually, if not precise your example data.

Comment: I have edited my question, the first if condition runs fine, but the second one starts with the oldest file instead of repsecting the 2nd condition after `-And ($fix -gt $latest))`

Comment: Referring to `execute files from 25 to 30` means index into $released or files `"TEMP Hotfix 20181025.file"` .. `"TEMP Hotfix 20181030.file"` ? BTW you notice there is a new Hotfix in there never mentioned before? In the latest code $rel is a sinlge element the `foreach ($i in $install)` makes no sense.

Comment: well `$install` at that point is array with strings (filenames) stored from that upgrade check and `$rel` is iteration item that i run checks against? Not sure if I understand correctly. The dates are different years and months, but when sorted they go from say 20140101 to the current date in correct order.

Comment: Well, you neeed a fresh mind or restart with a new question and a [mcve] the more changing details the unclearer your issue gets to  me.